# Momentjs and Flow types

Tags: javascript, momentjs, flowtype

I'm trying to learn how to use flow, but I'm stuck with an error message that makes no sense to me.

This is my code:

```js
import moment from "moment-timezone";
import type MomentType from "moment-timezone";

type filtersType = {
  page?: number,
  ccaa?: string,
  province?: string,
  date_from?: MomentType,
  date_to?: MomentType,
  distance_from?: number,
  distance_to?: number,
  category?: Array<string>,
};

const _parseValue = (value: mixed): string => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.join(",");
  else if (moment.isMoment(value)) return value.toISOString();
  else if (typeof value === "number") return value.toString();
  else if (typeof value === "string") return value;
  throw new Error("Filter value type is not valid!!");
};

const _generateQueryItem = (key: string, value: mixed): string => {
  return `${key}=${_parseValue(value)}`;
};

const _generateQuery = (filters: filtersType): string => {
  return Object.entries(filters)
    .map(([key, value]) => _generateQueryItem(key, value))
    .join("&");
};
```

It keeps complaining about this, on line 33:

```
Cannot call value.toISOString because property toISOString is missing in mixed [1].                

 [1] 30│ const _parseValue = (value: mixed): string => {
     31│   console.log(moment.isDate(value));
     32│   if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.join(",");
     33│   else if (moment.isMoment(value)) return value.toISOString();                            
     34│   else if (typeof value === "number") return value.toString();                            
     35│   else if (typeof value === "string") return value;
     36│   throw new Error("Filter value type is not valid!!");
```

I always though that mixed types includes everything so, it shouldn't complain about any method missing, I'm not sure on whats going on, I tried to change the args types to:

```
const _parseValue = (value: mixed | MomentType): string => {
```

and:

```
const _generateQueryItem = (key: string, value: mixed | MomentType): string => {
```

but I still get the same error.

I need a way to make flow know that `value` has `toISOString` method but I run out of ideas for today. How do I do that?

(I already have installed moment types with flow-typed btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, [type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/).

So you're trying to refine the type of `value`. You're doing this:

```
if (typeof value === "number") return value.toString();
```

which checks if `value` is a number. Flow understands this and refines `value` to a number so you can call `toString` on it.

You're doing this:

```
if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.join(",");
```

which checks if `value` is an array. Flow understands this and refines `value` to an array so you call `join` on it.

You're doing this:

```
if (moment.isMoment(value)) return value.toISOString();
```

which checks if `value` is an instance of a moment object. Flow does *not* understand this as a refinement. Therefore, your type is not being refined so when you attempt to call `toISOString` flow tells you that your method doesn't exist on `mixed`.

Flow only supports a small but somewhat powerful set of refinement operations. It has no idea that `isMoment` is even intended as a refinement. The only values flow can refine from `mixed` are really plain old data values, numbers, strings, arrays, objects, it's impossible to refine from `mixed` to `MomentType`.

So first of all, let's stop relying on `mixed`. If you can only possibly receive a small subset of types as parseable values, a [union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#union-type-syntax-) will serve you better, and it will explicitly add `MomentType` as a possibility for refinement:

```
type Parseable = number | string | string[] | MomentType;
```

Then there's the problem of our refinement for a moment object. Well, we have two possibilities. If we are really *only* concerned with these types, meaning we are totally confident these are the only things we will ever get, then we don't even have to explicitly refine to a moment object:

```
const _parseValue = (value: Parseable): string => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.join(",");
  else if (typeof value === "number") return value.toString();
  else if (typeof value === "string") return value;

  return value.toISOString(); // by process of elimination, this is a moment
};
```

Flow is smart enough to know that we have already handled all the other cases, so if we reach the end of the function then by process of elimination `value` must be a moment.

So, should we rely on this behavior? Well, it depends. Is arbitrary data from an unreliable API going to be passed into `_parseValue`? Or well-typed data from reliable places in our flow-typed codebase? If we don't need to worry too much about spurious data, then sure, rely on the process of elimination. Otherwise, we should probably hold onto your original error case. But that means we'll have to explicitly refine to our moment type:

```
const _parseValue = (value: Parseable): string => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.join(",");
  else if (typeof value === "number") return value.toString();
  else if (typeof value === "string") return value;
  // let's be extra careful
  else if (typeof value === 'object' && value.isMoment && value.toISOString) return value.toISOString();
  throw new Error("Filter value type is not valid!!");
};
```

Flow would accept our check `typeof value === 'object'` as enough to distinguish `value` from the other entries in `Parseable` and ensure that it is a `MomentType`, but as our data source might be dubious, let's also check for `value.isMoment` (a property on all moment objects defined in the flow-typed libdef for moment). This should prove beyond a reasonable doubt that this is, in fact, a moment object. One strategy would be to just duck-type any object that we get as having `value.toISOString` and go ahead and call it.